# HTTP Request to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to make an HTTP call to get the files content in drive using the below code:

```
string strbearer = 'Bearer '+strKey;
    string  strfileID = '1aIl4Sv**********hW'; 
    Http http = new Http(); 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');         
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/strfileID');         
    req.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');         
    req.setHeader('Authorization',strbearer);
    req.setTimeout(60*1000);      
    HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
```

but when i execute the above code i'm getting error as invalid credentials. please let me know if, this is the correct way to make a get request to drive using Apex(salesforce).

Comment: Do you know how to capture the request sent to the service? I'd be interested in seeing the raw request text.

Comment: Hi David, when i try to print the request output like req.toString(), my output looks like header body is not going[System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1aIl4SvQHxNloQ4ZAVbfHw, Method=GET]]

Comment: Looking at the output I see "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup". That tells me you need to signup for an account to allow more requests to be processed.